# Hide input field placeholder (textbox watermark) on focus after one second

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found out that with modern browsers I can hide an input's placeholder text (textbox watermark) by using this css:

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

<input id="txt_first_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
<input id="txt_last_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name">
```

and it works. My question is how can I hide the text in an animated way on focus after 1000 millisecond? Is there any jquery/javascript tricks for it?

Comment: It's called a placeholder. Why are you calling it a watermark?

Comment: I thought its also called watermark text.

Comment: The selector for Firefox is `[placeholder]:focus::-moz-placeholder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[`jsFIddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2Me4D/)***

I would suggest using the placeholder css with a class name. Then toggle the class name on and off the element on focus / blur.

css

```
.hideHolder[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/*moz support*/
.hideHolder[placeholder]:focus::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

js

```
var hideHolder = 0;
$('input[placeholder]').focus(function(){
 clearTimeout(hideHolder);
 var me = this;
 hideHolder = setTimeout(function(){
  $(me).addClass('hideHolder');       
 },1000);    
}).blur(function(){
 clearTimeout(hideHolder);
 $(this).removeClass('hideHolder');  
});
```

Comment: @LynHeadley - How about now?

Comment: Looks much sexier than mine :)

Comment: @TravisJ: yes, but now no ease-in/out like with Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the placeholder to an empty string after one second.

HTML:

```
<input class="removePlaceholder" id="txt_first_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your First Name">
<input class="removePlaceholder" id="txt_last_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name">
```

JS:

```
var tempPlaceholder;
var eraserTimeout;

$('.removePlaceholder').focus(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    tempPlaceholder = element.attr('placeholder');
    eraserTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        element.attr('placeholder', '');
    }, 1000);
}).blur(function() {
    clearTimeout(eraserTimeout);
    $(this).attr('placeholder', tempPlaceholder);
});
```

You can view it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvNz4/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about Webkit, you could use this (from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/hang-on-placeholders/)):

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    transition: opacity 1s 0.5s ease; 
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The above waits for 1 second, then does a CSS transition, fading out over 0.5 seconds.

To add Firefox support, this might work (haven't tested it):

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, [placeholder]:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    transition: opacity 1s 0.5s ease; 
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure that this is possible with IE though.